# How to make multiple smooth curves in one plot in R (with these data)?

Tags: r, plot, smoothing

I am a beginner with R. I have the next data:
5 cars drive from A to B, the total distance is 100 km. The speed of these cars is measured during different moments. On the x-axis the moment of measuring (in km) and on y-axis the speed at that moment.

I sorted my data in excel as on the picture: [Excelsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDyZ4.jpg).

I tried to plot these data with ggplot, but I didn't get any line and if I get lines, than they are not smooth. Also I want points at the place of measurements and give them a colour. And put a legenda next to it, like on the picture. On excel it is easy, but as beginner in R it is difficult. I tried already different methods.

Could anyone help me please?

[Second measurement data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kS1W.jpg)

Comment: Did you put your excel file into RStudio using read.csv or read_excel? If so, can you type, dput(df) where df is the name of your dataframe? Then copy and paste that output into your question and we can find a solution for you

Comment: One of the biggest things you will want to understand, going from Excel to R, is that while Excel wants to create a graph from a wide dataframe, R's ggplot method wants a long dataframe, so oftentimes there's a step of reshaping the data before graphing

Answer (score 0):

Most of the work is in the data munging. The plotting itself is straightforward.

```
# Data munging
tribble(~"Km1",~"Speed1",~"Km2",~"Speed2",~"Km3",~"Speed3",
        10,32,8,64,5,34,
        20,63,15,34,15,23,
        30,45,26,46,25,55,
        40,45,37,75,35,64,
        
        50,1,50,2,50,3) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = everything(),names_to = "Name",values_to = "Values") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Car = str_extract(Name,"\\d") %>% str_c("Car ",.),
                Name = str_replace(Name,"\\d","")) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Car,Name) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Values = str_c(Values,collapse = ",")) %>% 
  dplyr::slice(1) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = Car,names_from = Name,values_from = Values) %>% 
  tidyr::separate_rows(Km, Speed) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Km = as.numeric(Km),
                Speed = as.numeric(Speed)) 
  # Data plotting
  ggplot(aes(Km,Speed,color = Car)) +
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I just tried to put my other data in the script. 
I also have 4 cars with other measurements (i put them in the main post).
I wanted to put them in the tribble, but if I put a negative number and if I make one column with more rows, than I get an error. I couldn't fix this. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: And i also wanr to give the curves some of the cars green, some red and some orange colors

Comment: Remove any empty rows/columns before the start of the data in your excel sheet. Then import your excel sheet into R using readxl::read_excel("filepath/filename.xlsx"). Then remove the "tribble" part and just pipe the data into the rest of the code %>%

Comment: You can manually assign the colors by adding an extra line + scale_color_manual(values = c("orange","red","green"...)) depending on how many values you have and the order you want it in.

Comment: Negative numbers should not be a problem, but you cannot have more rows in one column than the other. Data wise, it doesn't make sense to have such a row.

Comment: It works only if i use the data of 2 cars. If I use the data of the cars with more measurements, than it doesn't work. How can I put the data in excel, so I can also use these data?

Comment: If you could import your data into excel using data <- readxl::read_excel("filepath/filename.xlsx") and then providing a dput(data) or head(data), it would be better. Reproducing is difficult if you provide your data as an image. But I've gone ahead and added car three and an extra row of data (speed and distance) to show that the code works for any number of cars and speeds.